# Boys and girls statistic problem

Tags: probability, statistics

In a class consisting of $18$ boys and $12$ girls the Professor
asks a question. Each boy has a probability $1/3$ to know the answer, while
corresponding probability for each girl is $1/2$. What is the expected
number of students who can answer correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ denote the number of boys that can answer the question correctly. Then $X=\sum_{i=1}^{18}X_i$ where $X_i=1$ if student $i$ knows the answer and $X_i=0$ else for $i=1,2,\ldots,18$. So $X$ is a sum of $n_X=18$ independent Bernoulli$(p=1/3)$ random variables and therefore is binomially distributed with parameters $n_X=18, p_X=1/3$. Hence $$E[X]=n_Xp_X=18\frac13=6$$ Similarly $Y \sim Bin(n_Y=12, p_Y=1/2)$ and hence $$E[Y]=n_Yp_Y=12\frac12=6$$ By linearity of expectation $$E[S]=E[X]+E[Y]=12$$

Comment: thank you again!! i thought this one  was more complicated but thank you for answering my question one more time!

Comment: @KYRIAKOS You are welcome (parakalw)!

Comment: eiste Ellhnas? 
how do you know im from greece?:)

Comment: @KYRIAKOS Nai, ellinas eimai! Harika, see you round!

Comment: Oooo kai gw xarika...na rwthsw...eimai foitiths prwto etos mhxanologwn kai paroti pantote eixa eyxairia me t mathimatika...ligo h statistikh m fainete ksenh...kai idios ayta...me thn stastikh...o logismos einai kalos p.x.. einai ayta ontos dyskola?